# Appropriate way to send real-time notifications

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, signalr

I want to create custom notification for my store of application(Applications for store was written using WPF). I have a server which will be send notification to user application. Is appropriate way to use real-time sockets for my purpose or I should ping my server sometime?

Comment: I think you mean UWP. It is using xaml but it is not WPF.

Comment: My team created own store